# PhpStorm and commands to remote server triggered by upload

Tags: symfony, ssh, phpstorm

Is it possible to make special commands like cleaning cache of Symfony on remote host automatically after upload files by <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible.

Watch these and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3344
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3239
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14114

---

Right now I may only suggest creating a custom Remote SSH External Tool entry which you can invoke when upload is complete.

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools

**NOTE:** You can assign a shortcut to such External Tool entry which you can press instead of invoking it via menu/toolbar button etc.